# Is it a good idea to use output stream to display text "in-game"?

Tags: c++, iostream, outputstream

Let's say I'm making a game where text can be displayed and scrolled/okay'd when ENTER is pressed.
Is it a good idea to use a output stream class and send my "raw" std::string to it? I'm thinking about doing this so it'd be easier to either send the messages to the console or to the actual screen using an fancy display style

thanks

Comment: This is a [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: @Hossein: No, not really.  He already has his design pretty much figured out, and now he's asking about implementation.

Comment: @Hossein: How is this even remotely a user-experience question?

Comment: OK I confess I misunderstood the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from making your own stream buffer class that can then forward to `std::cout` or do something more exotic at a later point in time.

I suggest reading this article here http://spec.winprog.org/streams/ about iostreams and rolling your own using what is provided to you.  Read this to gain an understanding of what is going on.

The Boost IO stream libraries make it even easier for you to create your own streams:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you "raw" string consists of printable text, there is nothing wrong with dumping the `std::string` to `std::cout` using `operator<<` to print it, for example:

```
// Display prompt to user
std::string output("Please press <ENTER>: ");

std::cout << output << std::flush;

// Wait for user to press <Enter>
std::string input;

std::getline(std::cin, input);
```